# Rails - collection_select does not select a values from tables having translations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, globalize

I am relatively new to RoR.
This works nicely:

```
<td><%= collection_select :competitions_members, :member_id, Member.all, :id, :first_name %></td>
```

This one picks no value (actually all such calls to tables with translations):

```
<td><%= collection_select :competitions_members, :tull_id, Tull.all, :id, :name %></td>
```

[seeded data in competitions_members table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Quu0M.png)

Member can be involved in many competition. Basically I have N:M relationship between members and competitions via competitions_members table.
Tull is a dictionary. Value to be set during the process of assigning members to a competition.

**Data model classes:**

```
class Member < ApplicationRecord
  has_and_belongs_to_many :competitions
end

class Competition < ApplicationRecord
  has_and_belongs_to_many :members
end

class CompetitionsMember < ApplicationRecord
end
```

Tull table has also translations in separate table.

```
class Tull < ApplicationRecord
  translates :name
  has_many :competitions_members

  # separate different localizations of the record
  def cache_key
    super + '-' + Globalize.locale.to_s
  end
end
```

**Relevant schema.db excerpt**

```
create_table "members", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "first_name"
    t.string   "last_name"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end
  create_table "competitions", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.datetime "created_at",       null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",       null: false
  end
  create_table "competitions_members", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer  "member_id"
    t.integer  "competition_id"
    t.datetime "created_at",       null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",       null: false
    t.integer  "tull_id"
    t.index ["tull_id"], name: "index_competitions_members_on_tull_id"
  end
  create_table "tull_translations", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer  "tull_id",    null: false
    t.string   "locale",     null: false
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.string   "name"
    t.index ["locale"], name: "index_tull_translations_on_locale"
    t.index ["tull_id"], name: "index_tull_translations_on_tull_id"
  end
  create_table "tulls", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end
```

Any help apreciated. I just realized this might be connected with translated tables somehow.

Comment: I can't find any reference to the `translates` directive in relation to Rails 5 ActiveRecord/AppplicationRecord, does it come from somewhere else?

Comment: I am using `gem 'globalize', github: 'globalize/globalize'`. More can be found here - https://github.com/globalize/globalize.

Answer (score 0):

```
class Tull < ApplicationRecord    
  has_many :translations
  translates :name, :fallbacks_for_empty_translations => true
  attr_accessible :translations_attributes
end
```

Try to execute below code in rails console:

`Tull.first.translations` - If this gives you translation records that means the associations are correct.

Now check at view side, how would you generate attributes for multilingual stuffs. I would suggest to use `globalize_accessors`.

Please send me the codebase.

Comment: Thank you. I have updated the class, tested via console and associations are correct - https://github.com/valasek/taekwondo/blob/master/app/models/tull.rb. But collection_select still does not show the correct values. It displays translated values but not selecting the value from the table. I just realized that values are not selected also for non-translated tables.